# How do I get the current user or current user id from a request in a controller (.Net 3.1 & React SPA Template)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, api, asp.net-core

Now the app is a SPA (Single Page Application) app, using ASP.NET Core 3.1 on the back-end and React 16.13.1 on the front-end. Specifically, I created the app using the 'dotnet' cli: `dotnet new react -o MyReactApp -au Individual`.

Anyway, I am having trouble getting the current logged in user (or even the current logged in user id) in a controller (or anywhere for that matter). I have tried so many things, and in every single case the current user and or the current user id is always being returned as NULL.

The first thing I tried was some code that worked in the last app I built, which used ASP.NET Core 3.1 & Angular (only difference being that the last app used angular instead of react). The code that worked to retrieve the current user in that last app was as follows:

Firstly in Startup.cs:

```c#
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Then in the Controller, first I imported the above (HttpContextAccessor) as well as the UserManger and some other helpful things:

```c#
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UserImgController(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        )
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
```

Next, I was able to retrieve the current logged in user like so:

```c#
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)
```

Lastly, I was able to retrieve the current logged in userId like so:

```c#
string userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

Now just to reiterate, that was the code I used with the last app I built, the ASP.NET Core 3.1 & Angular application. For whatever reason, that same code is NOT working with my latest app, the ASP.NET Core 3.1 & React application. Every method I have tried to either get the current "user" or the current "userId" is always returning NULL. Every. Time.

I am not exactly sure where ASP.NET Core gets the current user/userId from, which complicates the matter. However, I believe that every request sent by a logged in client to the server contains a cookie with either the sessionId and or the userId; And this is how the application manages to persist the state of a user.

Anyway, how do I get the current logged in user/userId from a request? Or why is it that despite there being a user that is logged in, the current logged in user/userId is always returned as NULL?

Comment: Did you try "services.AddHttpContextAccessor();" instead of "services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();"

Comment: @ArfizurRahman unfortrunately, yes I have :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?